# Unintended shaking effect while applying jQuery animate with chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm using the below code to create a full width full height website with sliding background images. it's all working fine with Firefox and IE but on Chrome and Safari the background is shaking during the animation. I also noticed the speed of the animation increasing overtime (not the actual var but it just seems to move faster after a while) any ideas on how to fix it or maybe a new solution to avoid animate() completely?

```js
$(function() {

    //settings for slider
    var width = '100%';
    console.log(width)
    var animationSpeed = 2000;
    var pause = 5000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    //cache DOM elements
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
    var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

    var interval;

    function startSlider() {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
                if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                }
            });
        }, pause);
    }
    function pauseSlider() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    $slideContainer
        .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
        .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

    startSlider();


});
```

```css
html,body {
 background-color:black;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
}

.col-md-1,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12,.row {
 padding: 0;
}
.header {
 background-color: white;
 height: 85px;
}

#slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 250px);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width: 600%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#slider .slide {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 16.666666667%;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer {
 color: white;
 height: 165px;
    padding: 72px 0  0 470px;
}

.slide1 {background: url('https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/people/grayscale') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;}
.slide2 {background: url('https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/people/grayscale') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;}
.slide3 {background: url('https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/people/grayscale') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;}
.slide4 {background: url('https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/people/grayscale') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;}
.slide5 {background: url('https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/people/grayscale') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/156x33">
        </div>
        <h1>Proin bibendum ligula massa nec maximus.</h1>
        <div id="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="slide slide1"></li>
                <li class="slide slide2"></li>
                <li class="slide slide3"></li>
                <li class="slide slide4"></li>
                <li class="slide slide5"></li>
                <li class="slide slide1"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: jQuery is not build for animating, so it has rather basic implementation. Probably the performance is just bad. I'd recommend Velocity.js as it's build with performance in mind.

Comment: I tried velocity. I have the same effect but less obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I posted is working fine now. It seems all browsers fixed the bugs.